# Trying to solve 2D Toda Lattice Equation with Lax Pair Approach

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, non-linear-systems, integrable-systems

I am working on this Hamiltonian:
$$ H = \frac{p_1^2 + p_2^2}{2m} + e^{q_2-q_1} + e^{q_2} + e^{-q_1} -3 $$
Thank you for the hint that it is a modification of the Toda Lattice Equation.
Let me sketch what I tried until now and why it is not working:
Analogous to the mentioned [publications](http://www.phy.bris.ac.uk/people/berry_mv/the_papers/Berry076.pdf) I introduced
 $$b_n:= \frac{1}{2}Exp{(\frac{q_n-q_{n+1}}{2})}\\
a_n:= -\frac{p_n}{2} $$
where it follows directly with $\frac{\partial  H}{\partial  q_i}=-p_i$ and $\frac{\partial  H}{\partial  p_i}=q_i$:
$$\dot{b_n} = (a_{n+1} - a_n)b_n \\
 \dot{a_n} = 2 (b_{n}^2 - b_{n-1}^2)$$
When now using the Lax Pair $L$,$B$:
$$ L f_n = b_n f_{n+1} +b_{n-1} f_{n-1} + a_n f_{n}$$

$$ B f_n = b_n f_{n+1} - b_{n-1} f_{n-1} $$
it can be shown that $\partial_t L=[B,L]$. My problem arises in defining the border conditions of my couple $q_1$ and $q_2$ in the 2d lattice above, since one needs to shift to the 3d representation $\{b_0,b_1,b_2\}$ in order to satisfy the periodic conditions (One mutual coordinate $q_3 = 0$ coupled to the others). Since it can be shown easily that $\dot{\lambda} = 0$ (where $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue $Lv=\lambda v$) the constants of motion reduce to the calculation of the eigenvalues. But in this case the eigenvalues of $L$ dont seem to simplify, in fact it doesnt seem to be a solution, which was my inital goal.

In general this approach seems to be at overkill for the 2d problem since it solves the n-dimensional Toda lattice.

1. Anyone knows of an easier approach to the 2d problem?
2. The Matrix $L$ seems to yield the wrong solution:
   $$ L = \begin{pmatrix}
   a_0 & b_0  & 0 \\ 
   b_0 & a_1 & b_1\\ 
   0 & b_1 & a_2 
   \end{pmatrix}$$
   The Matrix does neigher solve $\partial_t L = [B,L]$ (with $B=L_+ - L_-$) nor are eigenvalues constants of motion. Was has gone wrong?
3. Since the inverse scattering method can be applied here, I tried to get the scattering data, but actually I was not able to do the task. Any literature?

Comment: http://www.phy.bris.ac.uk/people/berry_mv/the_papers/Berry076.pdf has a discussion of the three-particle Toda lattice, which is what this is. The paper itself is a really good read, but that may give you a good start.

Comment: See [Toda lattice](http://www.google.com/search?as_q=Toda+lattice), e.g. [this](http://www.google.com/search?as_q=Toda+lattice+MillerLecture07).

Answer (score 0):

That's the Toda lattice, check, e.g., [here](http://www.google.com/search?as_q=Toda%20lattice%20MillerLecture07). Also, [Berry's paper](https://michaelberryphysics.files.wordpress.com/2013/07/berry076.pdf) has a discussion of the three-particle Toda lattice, which is what this is. The paper itself is a really good read, but that may give you a good start.