# Applications of Hamiltonian formalism in classical or celestial mechanics

Tags: classical-mechanics, orbital-motion, resource-recommendations, hamiltonian-formalism, celestial-mechanics

**I am looking for a reference (or just a brief explanation) to applications of the Hamiltonian formalism to classical mechanics, e.g. to planetary motion.**

In all known to me textbooks on classical mechanics explaining the Hamiltonian formalism (e.g. Landau-Lifshitz, vol. 1, or “Mathematical methods of classical mechanics” by Arnold) no applications to concrete problems of classical mechanics are given. (However  this formalism plays a role later in quantum mechanics to partly motivate the Schroedinger equation.)

Comment: Have you checked other texts?  There are 100s of textbooks on Hamiltonian methods, including books of problems with solutions, so it's difficult to answer such a broad question without some additional information.  Can you provide examples from this site?  There are >1700 questions tagged [tag:hamiltonian-formalism].  Curiously planetary motion is best treated using Lagrangian methods: see https://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/celestial/Celestial/Celestial.html

Comment: I must admit that I did not check 100s of books. For me a good answer would be an example of a concrete problem in classical/ celestial mechanics for whose solution the Hamiltonian formalism is necessary or at least useful. I do not mean exercises from textbooks, but problems of real interest.

Comment: what is a problem of real interest to you? Is this [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/205868/36194) the kind of example you want?  What about [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/110694/36194)?

Comment: An example of a problem of real interest for me is explanation of the  Kepler laws. (I know that they have nothing to do with Hamiltonian formalism) Another famous example is a theoretical prediction by astronomer Le Verrier of the planet Neptune. (I do not know whether Hamiltonian formalism played any role.)

Comment: Perturbation theory is quite complicated as you can see from the linked text by Fitzpatrick.  As to the Kepler problem, this is done via the action-angle formalism is Goldstein...